# Java EE Directory Structure

Tags: java, jsf, resources, internationalization

I have a problem with following tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/

In faces-context file you have to declare the place where all the language properties-files are (`<base-name>HERE</base-name>`). But in that example they use apparently maven2 and so they have a resource folder.

I am using eclipse and dynamic web project, that's why there is no resource folder. I tried a few possibilities like adding a new folder to the build path but I don't get it work.

Can you tell me please where to place those files to let my app find it. thank you so much

In addition I add a picture of my directory-structure:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They need to end up in the runtime classpath. The *WebContent* isn't part of the runtime classpath.

In your case, just drop them in the *Java Resources* folder. Imagine that they are placed in a package `com.example.i18n`, then you can specify as basename `com.example.i18n.locale` (although I would prefer `text` or `messages` over `locale` since they are actually no locale files).

#### Related:

- [How to internationalize a JSF 2.0 webapplication with UTF-8 properties files without native2ascii?](http://jdevelopment.nl/java/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/)