# In JSF, how to get redirected from WebContent/index.xhtml to WebContent/WEB-INF/index.xhtml

Tags: jsf-2

Please, Working with JSF, I want to know what I have to put inside my **WebContent/index.xhtml** in order to get redirected to **WebContent/WEB-INF/index.xhtml**
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're not easily able to access *.xhtml* files in the *WEB-INF*-folder because its not part of the Java EE specs and the server will answer any attempt of accessing a file with an 404 error. See [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/530570/Servlets/java/Accessing-files-under-WEB-INF).

You schould reconsider your intention and maybe create a separate folder for the files you want to access.

#### Methods for redirect

- **HTML meta-tag:** `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">`
- **JSP forward:** `<jsp:forward page="/your/page.xhtml" />`
- **Servlet:** get an *HttpServletResponse*-object and do `response.sendRedirect("/your/page.xhtml")`
- **JSF ManagedBean:** get the *ExternalContext* and do `extCtx.redirect("page.xhtml");`

Hope this helped, have Fun!

Comment: Thans for your contributions.
Finally I go through a navigation rule like this:

<navigation-rule>
 <from-view-id>/adm/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
 <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/WEB-INF/adm/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
 </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

Comment: Glad you found your solution! Please close your question or flag it as solved. Cheers!

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I dont see any 'close question' button.

Comment: No problem. I mean that you should please choose the anwswer which suits you best and mark it as the solution for your problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Be very cautious! What you are trying to do isn't a correct approach when it comes to Java EE guidelines.

The `WebContent/WEB-INF/` is not destined for web pages of any sort. There you should place only application related resources like:

- external libraries
- tag library descriptors
- config xml *(web.xml, faces-config.xml)*

[Here](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/code/projectconventions.html) you can find the correct structure of a Java EE Project. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669583/jee-directory-structure-question) you can find someone with almost the same problem.

In conclusion, your approach is not correct at all. You should revise your project structure in order to follow the official guidelines.